# C++ Exam Grader

Tags: c++, arrays

Alright, I've been able to simply the code. My current issue is dealing with the output. Looping structures to include 5 students but have the number elements reset like the percentages and answeredCorrectly. Also at the end of questions missed portion, I have to add in what the correct answer is. Our professor gave us 2 functions in order to accomplish this, I just do not understand how to implement them correctly. That code is not posted, but if anyone is interested in helping solve that problem, Ill be happy to post it.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <iomanip>
#include <string>
#include <fstream>
#include <sstream>
#include <cstdio>
using namespace std;

int main()
{
    int z = 0;
    const int WRONGQUESTIONS = 20;
    int wrongCounter[WRONGQUESTIONS];
    const int QUESTIONS = 20; 
    const int STUDENT_QUESTIONS = 100;
    ifstream inputFile;
    inputFile.open("CorrectAnswers.txt");
    char correctAnswers[QUESTIONS];
    for (int i=0; i<20; i++)
    {
        inputFile >> correctAnswers[i]; 
    }

    ifstream inputFile2;
    inputFile2.open("StudentAnswers.txt");
    char studentAnswers[STUDENT_QUESTIONS];
    for (int t=0; t<STUDENT_QUESTIONS; t++)
    {
        inputFile2 >> studentAnswers[t];
    }

int answeredCorrectly = 0;
for(int c = 0; c < 5; c++)
    {
        int z = 0;
    //now we use a for loop to go through the questions and store whether the answer was right or wrong
    for (int x = 0; x < QUESTIONS; x++)
        {      

            if (studentAnswers[x] == correctAnswers[x])
                answeredCorrectly++;
            else
                wrongCounter[z]++;
            z++;
        }
                cout << "Report for Student " << c+1 << ":" << endl;
                cout << "---------------------" << endl;
                cout << "Missed " << 20 - answeredCorrectly << " out of 20 questions for " << (answeredCorrectly / 20) * 100 << "% correct." << endl;
                cout << "Answered Correctly:  " << answeredCorrectly << endl;
                cout << "Questions missed:" << endl << endl;

    }
}
```

Comment: This code has a *lot* of problems. You should develop code in small stages, testing at each step. If you just type it in until it looks complete, this is what you get.

Comment: The exercise is to read bad code and fix it. I'm struggling with it too, its just hard to follow the logical progression of everything since I wasn't able to develop in chunks.

Comment: Unfortunately it is difficult to accommodate all levels of expertise on SO, and unfortunately I think this question is too beginner-level for SO. Sorry.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think I've found <strike>the</strike> a problem

```
while (badEntry = true)
```

use `==`

```
while (badEntry == true)
```

---

There are other issues too

```
while (badEntry = true)
{
        cout << "Invalid entry" << endl;// I GET AN INFINATE LOOP HERE????
        if (studentAnswers[x] == A || B)
                badEntry = false;
}
```

First off, what if none of the `studentAnswers` are equal to `A` or `B`?

Secondly, I think you want your `if` condition to be the following

```
if (studentAnswers[x] == A || studentAnswers[x] == B)
```

Comment: Or indeed, use proper logical operators and never make this mistake...  `while(badEntry)` or `while(!goodEntry)`.  Not to mention turning on compiler warnings, which would have caught this straight away.

Comment: I swear its the smallest damn things that always get me. I stared at this for half and hour changing every possible thing. Maybe coding isn't my thing.

Comment: No, don't be hard on yourself.  You've just gone through a rite of passage that most, if not all new C++ programmers will experience at some point.

Comment: I keep being told that one day it will just click. Right now its just a struggle for grades, but I genuinely want to learn this since I know it will help later on. Is the click a real thing, or is it just a constant struggle always?

Comment: @Simsyy I'm sure that you can think of some other things that might have been very difficult for you at some point in the past but are easy for you do do right now.  Things such as writing a 1 page paper, or basic trigonometry, etc.  Programming works much the same way.

Comment: Ok, I went ahead and edited the original post, changing the area where I got the infinite loop. Is that a suitable fix?

Comment: @Simsyy Why don't you run the code and see...

Comment: @simssy programming is just one of those things that takes hours upon hours of practice. But learning to read bad code and find the problems with it is a good starting point. This link may be of some use to you to better understand conditionals/if statements: http://www.cplusplus.com/forum/articles/3483/

Comment: Infinite loops again.

Comment: Yea, fixed that issue. If I cut out the code checking to see if its a good entry or not, it decides to work slightly. Now my main issue is that I am having to read through 100 answers, and the program is stopping at 20. Thing is, there have to be 5 separated students at 20 questions a pop.

Comment: The reason for that should be obvious if you're trying to work this out. If you don't know how to use a debugger, I would suggest just using a piece of paper. Write down the values of the variables after each line of code is executed, and walk yourself through the program's execution to figure out exactly what it's doing.

Comment: I was able to work that problem out, and now I am on to the output. Having issues with the logical repeating of an output that has to loop for each student, but the numbers must not stack on each other. It all just want to make me tear my hair out, and this will be going on hour number 5 on such a simple problem.

Answer (score 0):

You miss one "=" in "while (badEntry = true)". Should be "while (badEntry == true)". And in fact, you can do "while (badEntry)".

Same mistake for "if (studentAnswers[y] = 'N')".

To avoid such problems, you should always put the constant first. For example, do "if ('N' == studentAnswers[y])".

Comment: same bug lower down to, `if (studentAnswers[y] = 'N')`

Comment: Yeah. In most languages, including Java, a `==` _checks_ a value, while a `=` _sets_ a value. If you set the value when you're trying to check a value, you're almost guaranteed to have it do something funky. ;)

Comment: It's not fair to state that "you should always put the constant first".  While that style is devised explicitly to avoid these errors, there are some software houses who rigorously oppose its use, because it's unnatural to read.

Answer (score 0):

Couple of problems:  `while (badEntry = true)` will set badEntry to true every time it checks the conditional. So it ends up checking `while(true)` (aka infinite loop). As others have said, use `while(badEntry)`instead.

Furthermore, `if (studentAnswers[x] == A || B)` is also incorrect. It should be: `if ( (studentAnswers[x] == 'A') || (studentAnswers[x] == 'B') )`

Furthermore, `if (studentAnswers[x] == 'A' || 'B')` is interpreted as: 
`if ( (studentAnswers[x] == 'A') || ('B') )` which will come out to true every time because 'B' is non-null. You were also missing the quotations around the letter to denote it as a character.

You may find this helpful: http://www.cplusplus.com/forum/articles/3483/

Answer (score 0):

This isn't the main issue, other people have already posted the real problem. However, this also happens to make your program not work properly.

`if (studentAnswers[x] != A || B)` is an interesting conditional.

I imagine you were testing if **studentAnswers[x]** wasn't equal to either **A** or **B**. 
 You can't say this in C++ or with (what I aware of) most languages.

Your statement would parse to `if((studentAnswers[x] != A) || B)`.
 ( `!=` comes before `||` in binary operator precedence). To fix this, just create a != check for both A and B.

It should look like this: `if (studentAnswers[x] != A || studentAnswers[x] != B)`.
The same goes for `==`.

---

Just looked up to see that "Sam I am" put this in his answer already. Sorry about that.
Anyways, be wary of your boolean test, that seems to be what screwed up most of the program.

**EDIT:** Looks like "TonyArra" also said the same thing, oops. Well at least you'll remember now.

Comment: yeah this question attracted a flock of users that can't stand poorly-written conditional statements.

Comment: Sorry, still getting the hang of things